# how can Matlab GUI access a variable in a running Matlab script?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

GUI (from guide) has button that does:   go;
go.m is a script that runs endless loop.

GUI has a SHUTDOWN button that needs to set variable: script_should_run = false;
When script go.m detects
script_should_run = false;
 it will end the endless loop.

How can GUI.m control variable script_should_run in go.m ?

Comment: `assignin('base','script_should_run',false)` ... but for real I would recommend to not run _script_ from your gui, package everything in functions, it is much neater and you'll have more control on your scopes.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would not advice to use global variables, it would be better to put the variable in the workspace and read from it in your infinite loop. Try the following sample program. It is not a GUI created from guide but it is the same way to do.

```
%GUI with two buttons
function Untitled
   uicontrol('Position',[20,20,60,25],'String','go','Callback',@go_callback);
   uicontrol('Position',[100,20,100,25],'String','SHUTDOWN','Callback',@stop_callback);
end

function go_callback(varargin)
   script_should_run = 1;
   assignin('base','script_should_run',1)
   while(script_should_run == 1)
       script_should_run = evalin('base','script_should_run');
       disp('go')
       pause(0.1) %need to pause else MATLAB will ignore when you push the stop button
   end
end

function stop_callback(varargin)
  assignin('base','script_should_run',0)
end
```